# Cannot read input file

Tags: java, image, window, jframe

I'm trying to display an image onto my program, but I'm having some difficulty.

```
public static BufferedImage background;
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    try {
        background = ImageIO.read(new File("background.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Display game = new Display();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon());
    frame.add(game);
    frame.add(label);
    frame.pack();
            // JFrame configurating
}
```

The program cannot read the file from the path specified. This is the package explorer:
[image: package explorer]

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Please define - "cannot read".

Comment: This is the error:
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1275)                       
at me.Voltex.Display.main(Display.java:27)

Comment: You're reading the image into `background` but then you're not doing anything with `background.` Try *using* it somewhere.

Comment: You cannot use the file "background.jpg" as this file does not exist where you are expecting it. Look at the screenshot. You only placed a link into the folder "Images". This link is managed by Eclipse itself. Physically, there is nothing inside.

Answer (score 1):

The default location is the project folder `"EasyAdmin"`. But your image is inside a folder called `"Images"`, so you have to specify it:

```
background = ImageIO.read(new File("Images\\background.jpg"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by it still doesn't work? It throws the same exception? This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the image is part of the application. The way you set-up your project, it's part of your classpath, which is a good idea. This means you should load it likt this:

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("background.jpg");
background = ImageIO.read(new File(url.toURI()));
```

Comment: File cannot convert from URL to String (Which it needs). Casting doesn't seem to work. Solutions?

Comment: URL provides the URI, which File takes as input. I correct the code in the answer.